# Joda Time - String to DateTime conversion

Tags: elasticsearch, jodatime

I require some help converting the following `Thu, 13 Feb 2014 16:43:58 +0000` string to type DateTime. I have a stream of tweets being stored in an ElasticSearch cluster, currently the timestamp of each tweet is mapped as a string. I wish to parse these to type DateTime.

I tried `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ` but it failed. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what/how you tried.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I did, it's above. Must be that bad you can't see it.

Comment: @NSmeef: Well you've shown the pattern - but *nothing* else about the code. For example, you haven't shown whether or not you specified an English locale... (And being dismissive of people who are trying to help you is never a good plan.)

Comment: @JonSkeet ElasticSearch uses JodaTime to parse String objects to DateTime, all I have is a mapping of my type and an example of the string I want to convert. Removed Java tag to remove confusion.

Comment: @NSmeef: Hopefully ElasticSearch uses an English locale by default... but it would help if you would edit the question to give more context. Just having `elasticsearch` as a tag isn't as useful as the information about performing a mapping etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only want a single `Z` to represent "offset without a colon".

Also note that you should ensure that your `DateTimeFormatter` is using English month/day names.

For example:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter format =
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z")
                .withLocale(Locale.US);
        String text = "Thu, 13 Feb 2014 16:43:58 +0000";
        System.out.println(format.parseDateTime(text));
    }
}
```